# SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17093 null

Tags: java, android, firebase-authentication

I have an existing app which I have already tested on numerous occasions. Suddenly, on this day I am getting the error: SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17093 null, when I try to register a new user. Previously I have been able to register 5 dummy users. I have looked around here for answers, however, most of the solutions assume that one has not yet set up SHA signatures. But as I have said, I have already done this. I'd appreciate your guidance on how to resolve this matter. Thanks in advance.

The code for particular activity:

```
`package com.example.e_mall;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseException;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class PhoneRegisterCodeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String verificationId;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    EditText editText;
    Button buttonSignIn, buttonOk;
    TextView textView;
    RelativeLayout cardView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_phone_register_code);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        editText = findViewById(R.id.et_verify_code);
        buttonSignIn = findViewById(R.id.btn_submit_login_code);
        buttonOk = findViewById(R.id.btn_submit_back);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.tv_banner_2);

        buttonOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(PhoneRegisterCodeActivity.this, PhoneLoginAuthActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });

        buttonSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String code = editText.getText().toString().trim();

                if (code.isEmpty() || code.length() < 6) {

                    editText.setError("Enter code...");
                    editText.requestFocus();
                    return;
                }
                verifyCode(code);
            }
        });

    }

    private void verifyCode(String code) {
        PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationId, code);
        signInWithCredential(credential);
    }

    private void signInWithCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            String number = getIntent().getStringExtra("Number");

                            Intent intent = new Intent(PhoneRegisterCodeActivity.this, AddUserData.class);
                            intent.putExtra("number", number);
                            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();

                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(PhoneRegisterCodeActivity.this, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    private void sendVerificationCode(String number) {
        PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
                number,
                60,
                TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                this,
                mCallBack
        );

    }

    private PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
            mCallBack = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {

        @Override
        public void onCodeSent(String s, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
            super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);
            verificationId = s;
        }

        @Override
        public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
            String code = phoneAuthCredential.getSmsCode();
            if (code != null) {
                editText.setText(code);
                verifyCode(code);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
            Toast.makeText(PhoneRegisterCodeActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() == null) {

            String number = getIntent().getStringExtra("phoneNumber");
            sendVerificationCode(number);

            // save phone number
            SharedPreferences prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("USER_PREF",
                    Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putString("phoneNumber", number);
            editor.apply();
            //Toast.makeText(this, "Please register first before using this service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            editText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            buttonSignIn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            buttonOk.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            textView.setText("You are already registered. Please login");
            textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            cardView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        }
    }
}`
```

Logcat:

```
    I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
    (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
E/FirebaseAuth: [SmsRetrieverHelper] SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17093 null
D/Toast: show: focusDisplayId = 0, isFocusInDesktop = false mCustomDisplayId=-1
V/Toast: SHOW: android.widget.Toast$TN@242ea6e
V/Toast: HANDLE SHOW: android.widget.Toast$TN@242ea6e mView=null mNextView=android.widget.LinearLayout{8ff850f V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0}
    HANDLE HIDE: android.widget.Toast$TN@242ea6e mView=null
I/ViewRootImpl@1b73f7a[Toast]: setView = android.widget.LinearLayout@8ff850f TM=true MM=false
V/Toast: Text: Uhis in android.widget.Toast$TN@242ea6e
I/ViewRootImpl@1b73f7a[Toast]: Relayout returned: old=(0,45,720,1516) new=(58,1201,662,1404) req=(604,203)0 dur=54 res=0x7 s={true 3987847168} ch=true
I/ViewRootImpl@1b73f7a[Toast]: MSG_RESIZED: frame=(58,1201,662,1404) ci=(0,0,0,0) vi=(0,0,604,203) or=1
V/Toast: HIDE: android.widget.Toast$TN@242ea6e
V/Toast: HANDLE HIDE: android.widget.Toast$TN@242ea6e mView=android.widget.LinearLayout{8ff850f V.E...... ........ 0,0-604,203}
    REMOVE! android.widget.LinearLayout{8ff850f V.E...... ........ 0,0-604,203} in android.widget.Toast$TN@242ea6e
I/ViewRootImpl@1b73f7a[Toast]: dispatchDetachedFromWindow
D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: 'f963872', fd=91
V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
I/ViewRootImpl@430e7b6[PhoneRegisterCodeActivity]: ViewPostIme key 0
I/ViewRootImpl@430e7b6[PhoneRegisterCodeActivity]: ViewPostIme key 1
V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 255189
V/FA: Connecting to remote service
I/ViewRootImpl@430e7b6[PhoneRegisterCodeActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0 1
D/InputMethodManager: prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@22254f6[PhoneRegisterCodeActivity]
    getNavigationBarColor() -855310
V/FA: Activity paused, time: 798550510
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
D/FA: Connected to remote service
V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 2
D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: 'ClientS', fd=87
I/ViewRootImpl@430e7b6[PhoneRegisterCodeActivity]: Relayout returned: old=(0,0,720,1600) new=(0,0,720,1600) req=(720,1600)8 dur=17 res=0x5 s={false 0} ch=true
I/ViewRootImpl@430e7b6[PhoneRegisterCodeActivity]: stopped(true) old=false
I/ViewRootImpl@430e7b6[PhoneRegisterCodeActivity]: dispatchDetachedFromWindow
D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: '99801aa', fd=80
W/System: A resource failed to call end. 
D/FA: Application going to the background
V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
```